# Python Read/Write csv file

Tags: python, csv

Reading and writing data from/to csv file. When I run the program its formatted correctly in the console window, however, the formatting is off in the csv file I'm writing to (has a comma after each letter). What am I missing here?

[image]

[image]

```
import csv

with open("WJU stats.csv", 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

with open('wjudata.csv', 'w') as new_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(new_file)

    for row in csv_reader:
        csv_writer.writerow(row[0])
        print(row[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `writerow` takes an `iterable`, for example a `list`, so it writes each element of the iterable to the file in a comma separated row. The thing is strings are also iterables which elements are characters. If you want a single column csv you should use

```
csv_writer.writerow([row[0]])
```

Comment: I see. By enclosing each string element in [ ] then the writer treats each string as a list. That did the trick...thanks.